# In jui\datepicker date format is not working in first form while using wbraganca dynamic form

Tags: yii2

I am using `wbraganca` dynamic form, in this dynamic form datepicker date format is not working correctly in first form.code is given below-

```
<?= $form->field($modelNominee, "[{$i}]dateOfMarriage")->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [
            'language' => 'en-UK',
            'dateFormat' => "dd/M/yyyy",
            'options' => ['class'=>'cust-form-control marriage-date','placeholder'=>'Date of Marriage','autocomplete'=>'off','readOnly'=>true,'aria-label' => 'Date of Marriage'],
            'clientOptions'=>[
              'changeMonth'=>true,
              'changeYear'=> true,
              'maxDate'=> '+0',                
            ],
        ])->label(false
```

Comment: Please use proper formatting for your code.

Comment: ok,  next time I will take care of that

Comment: what do you mean by not working, what is the actual behavior that you are encountering, throws an error? breaks layout? stays blank? shows incorrect format as compared to what you are specifying?